# Set width of 'selection checkbox' column in ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have customized `checkboxCellTemplate` in my table using ng-grid. I want to show there checkbox **and some text**, but I don't know how to set width of this column.

Unfortunately `minWidth` is not working for checkbox column.

```
$scope.gridOptions = { 
    data: 'myData',
    showSelectionCheckbox: true,
    checkboxCellTemplate: '<div class="ngSelectionCell"><input tabindex="-1" class="ngSelectionCheckbox" type="checkbox" ng-checked="row.selected" /> Some text here</div>',
};
```

[Here is JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9kCr/1/). Any iedas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found it is better to avoid overriding ngGrid's column widths and placement via CSS

A better route is to forgo the showSelectionCheckbox option and place your own checkbox in the columnDefs like so

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'myData',
        columnDefs: [{
            field: '',
            minWidth: 120,
            cellTemplate: '<div class="ngSelectionCell"><input tabindex="-1" class="ngSelectionCheckbox" type="checkbox" ng-checked="row.selected" /> Some text here</div>'
          }, {
            field: 'name'
          }, {
            field: 'age'
            }
        ]

    };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k9kCr/19/

Comment: Yes, that is something I've done in the end. No hacks needed.

Answer (score 1):

After looking through their source and docs, I agree that `ng-grid` doesn't provide any/many convenient hooks to extend or customize the display and text on the row selection functionality it provides.

However, they do have a consistent naming scheme for it's generated rows and columns. For example, the first column is tagged as `colt0`, the second as `colt1` and so on. These generated classes are also applied to each row in the `ng-repeat` but that's less important here.

In any case, I was able to apply some CSS to extend the display to widen the selection column and display your provided text. I'm not particularly happy with the CSS since I had to override some inline style attributes with `!important` to breakout from specificity rules.

In any case, here's *a* solution:

```
/* This widens the length of the first column */
.colt0 {
    width: 140px !important;
}

/* The second (zero-indexed!) column needs to be moved out to accomodate a wider first column */
.colt1 {
    left: 150px !important;
}

/* Move the position of the header checkbox a few pixels left */
.ngSelectionHeader {
    left: 11px;
}

/* Move the position of the viewport checkboxes to accomodate their new wider row containers */
.ngSelectionCell {
    margin-left: 11px;
}
```

**JSFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/MasterXen/9BpUR/2/**

Comment: Yeah, so this one is dirty, but for now the only working solution

Answer (score -1):

You can do that via columnDefs.

```
    app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.myData = [
            {name: "Moroni", age: 50},
            {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
            {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
            {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
            {name: "Enos", age: 34}
        ];
        $scope.gridOptions = {
            data: 'myData',
            showSelectionCheckbox: true,
            columnDefs: [
                {field: '', width: '50px'
                },
                {field: 'name'
                },
                {field: 'age'
                }
            ]
        };
    });
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xNb6J/)

Comment: Nah, this does not really work, it just looks like it's working because I forgot to delete the CSS definintion for colt0 from my first try. Better go for @Ishan Chatterjees answer. I wanted to do same in my first attempt.